# Python shell says I have not provided 2 specific arguments, but I believe I have. How can I solve this?

Tags: python, arguments

I believe I have provided the arguments to username and directory in the following code. However, when I try to run it, this error comes up:

> error: the following arguments are required: username, directory

Here is the code:

```
def __init__(self, username='styledbyme', directory="c:\python34\images",
             num_to_download = 10, log_level='info'):
    self.username = username
    self.profile_url = self.get_url(username)
    self.directory = directory
    self.PAUSE = 1
    self.user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
    self.headers = {'User-Agent': self.user_agent}
    self.html_source = None
    self.log_level = getattr(logging, log_level.upper())
    self.setup_logging(self.log_level)
    self.set_num_posts(num_to_download)
    self.setup_webdriver()
```

I have tried searching other answers and google but no luck. Kindly assist with this. I am a python beginner.

Comment: why is there a `*` in front of `username`?

Comment: what is the exact error trace and how are you calling it?

Comment: What happens if you use "c:\\python34\\images" with double backslashes?

Comment: This error probably comes from [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#getting-a-little-more-advanced) module, however in your code snippet there is no call to argparse so this is not the place where error comes from.

Comment: How do you instantiate the object???

Comment: @running.t thanks. I think it has to do with the parse argument. I just added the arguments: 

     parser.add_argument('styledbyme', help='Instagram username')
     parser.add_argument('c:\python34\images\styledbyme', help='Where to save the images')

But another error comes up: 

error: the following arguments are required: styledbyme, c:\python34\images\styledbyme

Comment: @od320: This time you used add_argument wrong way. [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method) is documentation of this method. First parameted of `add_argument` is name or flags of argument. So I think it should be something like `parser.add_argument('username', default='styledbyme', help='...')`. Anyway, if you could edit your question and paste parts of code more apropriate to your question we would be able to help you and show what is exactly wrong.

Comment: @od320: It also looks your code is not some super hyper secret rocket science so don't worry, no one will steal it :p

Comment: @running.t: Thanks. please find the entire code in link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844987/python-does-not-state-the-line-of-code-that-an-error-refers-to