# Python does not state the line of code that an error refers to

Tags: python, arguments, instagram, argparse

I have tried to correct the following error which basically is about the arguments for 'username' and 'directory'. I have tried all possible ways but no luck. Python does not state the line of code that the following error refers to:

```
usage: Google_Map.py [-h] [-n NUM_TO_DOWNLOAD] [-l LOG_LEVEL]
                     username directory
Google_Map.py: error: the following arguments are required: username, directory
```

Please see the code here:

```
def __init__(self, username, directory, num_to_download = 10,
             log_level='info'):
    self.username = username
    self.profile_url = self.get_url(username)
    self.directory = directory
    self.PAUSE = 1
    self.user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
    self.headers = {'User-Agent': self.user_agent}
    self.html_source = None
    self.log_level = getattr(logging, log_level.upper())
    self.setup_logging(self.log_level)
    self.set_num_posts(num_to_download)
    self.setup_webdriver()

def get_url(self, path):
    return urlparse.urljoin('https://instagram.com', path)

def set_num_posts(self, num_to_download=None):
    self.num_posts = int(self.get_posts_count(self.profile_url) or 0)
    self.num_to_download = num_to_download

def setup_logging(self, level=logging.INFO):
    self.logger = logging.getLogger('instaraider')
    self.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def log(self, *strings, **kwargs):
    level = kwargs.pop('level', logging.INFO)
    self.logger.log(level, u' '.join(str(s) for s in strings))

def setup_webdriver(self):
    self.profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    self.profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", self.user_agent)
    self.webdriver = webdriver.Firefox(self.profile)
    self.webdriver.set_window_size(480, 320)
    self.webdriver.set_window_position(800, 0)

def get_posts_count(self, url):
    """
    Given a url to Instagram profile, return number of photos posted
    """
    response = requests.get(url)
    counts_code = re.search(r'\"media":{"count":\d+', response.text)
    if not counts_code:
        return None
    return re.findall(r'\d+', counts_code.group())[0]

def log_in_user(self):
    driver = self.webdriver
    self.log('You need to login to access this profile.',
             'Redirecting you to the login page in the browser.',
             level=logging.WARN)
    driver.get(self.get_url('accounts/login/'))

    # Wait until user has been successfully logged in and redirceted
    # to his/her feed.
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.-cx-PRIVATE-FeedPage__feed'),
        )
    )

    self.log('User successfully logged in.', level=logging.INFO)
    self.set_num_posts()  # Have to set this again
    driver.get(self.profile_url)

def load_instagram(self):
    """
    Using Selenium WebDriver, load Instagram page to get page source
    """
    self.log(self.username, 'has', self.num_posts, 'posts on Instagram.')
    if self.num_to_download is not None:
        self.log("The first", self.num_to_download, "of them will be downloaded.")

    num_to_download = self.num_to_download or self.num_posts
    driver = self.webdriver
    # load Instagram profile and wait for PAUSE
    self.log("Loading Instagram profile...")
    driver.get(self.profile_url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(self.PAUSE)

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    try:
        el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            '.-cx-PRIVATE-ProfilePage__advisoryMessageHeader'
        )
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        self.log_in_user()

    if (num_to_download > 24):
        scroll_to_bottom = self.get_scroll_count(num_to_download)
        element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.-cx-PRIVATE-AutoloadingPostsGrid__moreLoadingIndicator a')
        driver.implicitly_wait(self.PAUSE)
        element.click()

        for y in range(int(scroll_to_bottom)):
            self.scroll_page(driver)

    # After load all profile photos, retur, source to download_photos()
    time.sleep(1)
    source = driver.page_source

    # close Firefox window
    driver.close()

    return source

def scroll_page(self, driver):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0);")

def get_scroll_count(self, count):
    return (int(count) - 24) / 12 + 1

def validate(self):
    """
    returns True if Instagram username is valid
    """
    req = requests.get(self.profile_url)

    try:
        req.raise_for_status()
    except:
        self.log('User', self.username, 'is not valid.',
                 level=logging.ERROR)
        return False

    if not self.num_posts:
        self.log('User', self.username, 'has no photos to download.',
                 level=logging.ERROR)
        return False
    return True

def save_photo(self, photo_url, photo_name):
    image_request = requests.get(photo_url, headers=self.headers)
    image_data = image_request.content
    with open(photo_name, 'wb') as fp:
        fp.write(image_data)

    if "last-modified" in image_request.headers:
        modtime = calendar.timegm(eut.parsedate(image_request.headers["last-modified"]))
        os.utime(photo_name, (modtime, modtime))

def download_photos(self):
    """
    Given source code for loaded Instagram page,
    extract all hrefs and download full-resolution photos
    source: HTML source code of Instagram profile papge
    """
    num_to_download = self.num_to_download or self.num_posts
    if self.html_source is None:
        self.html_source = self.load_instagram()

    # check if directory exists, if not, make it
    if not op.exists(self.directory):
        os.makedirs(self.directory)

    # index for progress bar
    photos_saved = 0
    self.log("Saving photos to", self.directory)

    links = re.findall(r'src="[https]+:...[\/\w \.-]*..[\/\w \.-]*..[\/\w \.-]*..[\/\w \.-].jpg', self.html_source)

    for link in links:
        photo_url = link[5:]
        photo_url = photo_url.replace('\\', '')
        photo_url = re.sub(r'/s\d+x\d+/', '/', photo_url)

        split = urlparse.urlsplit(photo_url)
        photo_name = op.join(self.directory, split.path.split("/")[-1])

        # save full-resolution photo if its new
        if not op.isfile(photo_name):
            self.save_photo(photo_url, photo_name)
            photos_saved += 1
            self.log('Downloaded file {}/{} ({}).'.format(
                photos_saved, num_to_download, op.basename(photo_name)))
        else:
            self.log('Skipping file', photo_name, 'as it already exists.')

        if photos_saved >= num_to_download:
            break

    self.log('Saved', photos_saved, 'files to', self.directory)


def main():
    # parse arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='InstaRaider')
    parser.add_argument('username', help='Instagram username')
    parser.add_argument('directory', help='Where to save the images')
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--num-to-download',
                        help='Number of posts to download', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--log-level', help="Log level", default='info')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    username = args.username
    directory = op.expanduser(args.directory)

    raider = InstaRaider(username, directory,
                         num_to_download=args.num_to_download,
                         log_level=args.log_level)

    if not raider.validate():
        return

    raider.download_photos()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you tell us your execution? what command you used?

Comment: That's not a Python exception message. That's *command line help output*.

Comment: Look at the `argparse` code at the bottom. You need to provide arguments to run the script.

Comment: You ran your program with something like `python Google_Map.py` without specifying the required `username` and `directory` arguments. This is the error message generated by `parser.parse_args()` before exiting the program.

Comment: I have tried to specify the required arguments at argparse code but it still outputs this error message: error: the following arguments are required: username, directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a Python exception message. That's *command line help output*.

The output is generated by the `argparse` module, configured here:

```
def main():
    # parse arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='InstaRaider')
    parser.add_argument('username', help='Instagram username')
    parser.add_argument('directory', help='Where to save the images')
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--num-to-download',
                        help='Number of posts to download', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--log-level', help="Log level", default='info')
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

The moment `parser.parse_args()` is called your command line arguments are parsed to match the above configuration.

Specifically, the `username` and `directory` positional arguments are *required*:

```
parser.add_argument('username', help='Instagram username')
parser.add_argument('directory', help='Where to save the images')
```

You'll need to specify these on the command line when you run the script:

```
Google_Map.py some_instagram_username /path/to/directory/to/save/images
```

The other command line options are *optional* and start with `-` or `--`.

If you can't run this from a console or terminal command line, you could pass in the options to the parser directly:

```
def main(argv=None):
    # parse arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='InstaRaider')
    parser.add_argument('username', help='Instagram username')
    parser.add_argument('directory', help='Where to save the images')
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--num-to-download',
                        help='Number of posts to download', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--log-level', help="Log level", default='info')
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    # ....

main(['some_instagram_username', '/path/to/directory/to/save/images'])
```

Now the arguments are passed in via the `argv` optional function parameter, as a list.

However, rather than have `main()` parse arguments, you could just use the `InstaRaider()` class directly:

```
raider = InstaRaider('some_instagram_username', '/path/to/directory/to/save/images')
raider.download_photos()
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what is the implication that it is a command line help output? would i need to run the code on command prompt? Also, what does it mean to specify on the command line? Can I do all these within the idle python shell environment?

Comment: @od320: Normally you'd run this via the command prompt, yes. I've updated my answer to show how you could programatically pass in arguments to `parser.parse_args()` instead.

Comment: @od320: the better option is to not use the `main()` function, but just call the class directly just like the `main()` function does; all that function does is configure the class from the command line.